# Why can't a MySQL database, connected to my android app, be updated?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, post

Here is the PHP file codes to connect to the MySQL database testing and the Java code to pass the data to PHP. Please help me find the error.  It won't update the database when I run it. However, I can use PHP to update the database and it will show.

**PHP file:**

```
<?php

 $db_name = "testing";
 $mysql_user = "root";
 $mysql_pass = "squidoo";
 $server_name = "localhost";
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name)
 ?>

<?php
 require "dbconfigure.php";

 $firstname = isset($_POST["Firstname"])? $_POST["Firstname"]:null;
 $lastname = isset($_POST["Lastname"])? $_POST["Lastname"]:null;
 $birthdate = isset ($_POST["Birthdate"])? $_POST["Birthdate"]:null;
 $email = isset($_POST["email"])? $_POST["email"]: null;
 $username =  isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : null;
 $password = isset ($_POST["password"])? $_POST['username'] : null;
 $sql_query = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, birthdate,        
 email,username,password)  
  VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$birthdate','$email','$username','$password');";

?>
```

**JAVA file:**

```
package com.example.sony.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

String firstname, lastname, birthdate, email, username, password;

EditText FirstName, LastName, Email, BirthDate, NewUsername, NewPassword;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);



    FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
    LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LastName);
    BirthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BirthDate);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    NewUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewUsername);
    NewPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewPassword);


}

public void userReg(View view) {

    firstname = FirstName.getText().toString();
    lastname = LastName.getText().toString();
    birthdate = BirthDate.getText().toString();
    email = Email.getText().toString();
    username = NewUsername.getText().toString();
    password = NewPassword.getText().toString();

    String method = "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, firstname, lastname, birthdate, email, username, password);
    finish();

      }


 }

package com.example.sony.testing;

      import android.app.AlertDialog;
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.os.AsyncTask;
     import android.widget.Toast;
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.BufferedWriter;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.io.OutputStream;
     import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
     import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
     import java.net.MalformedURLException;
     import java.net.URL;
     import java.net.URLEncoder;


 public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;
  public BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{

    this.ctx =ctx;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information");
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];


    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String Firstname = params[1];
        String Lastname = params[2];
        String Birthdate = params[3];
        String email= params[4];
        String username = params[5];
        String password = params[6];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("Firstname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Firstname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("Lastname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Lastname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("Birthdate","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Birthdate,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: in the php side your are missing to execute query

Comment: add this line `mysql_query($sql_query,$con)`

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know. I don't know much php, just want to connect my database to the app :/

Comment: In this case, you want to do `mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)`.

Comment: thanks for the correction @budwiser

Comment: @budwiser Thank you! It's working!

Comment: Note that this question, and the answer from Suyog below, have SQL injection vulnerabilities - do not use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are missing execute the insert query. You can use `mysqli_query` to do so.
Following it the code in which most of the conditions are handled to get better response in your app.

**Note: The response of query is given here in JSON as it is to be passed to android application.**

```
$db_name = "testing";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "squidoo";
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// check all parameters are with values
$firstname = isset($_POST["Firstname"]) ? $_POST["Firstname"]:null;
$lastname = isset($_POST["Lastname"]) ? $_POST["Lastname"]:null;
$birthdate = isset ($_POST["Birthdate"]) ? $_POST["Birthdate"]:null;
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"]: null;
$username =  isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password = isset ($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST['username'] : null;

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, birthdate,        
 email,username,password)  
  VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$birthdate','$email','$username','$password')";

 // execute the query
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)) 
{
    $data = array('result' => 'success', 'message' => 'Successfully user added!');
} 
else 
{
    $data = array('result' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error while registration!');
}

// close the connection
mysqli_close($con);

/* JSON Response */
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear, helpful explanation! Definitely learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you never executed the SQL query and so it can't insert your data to the database. Execute the SQL and I think it will surely work.

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)
```

**Note: you need to use mysqli prepared statements**, since you are presently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working fine! I have been trying to debug this for hours, couldn't find any errors. Checked the db connection and since the connection was established I thought it was for sure my java codes.

Comment: @squidoo Remeber to use mysqli prepared statements in order to prevent sql injection

Comment: Yeap, I came across that! Need to learn it. haha. Will be sure to fix that! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can anyone tell me what url do I have to use if I want to run the app on my device as opposed to the emulator?